# How to zip the standard output of a process?

Tags: gzip, compression

I have a process that is producing a big amount of log to the standard output in a short period of time. Is there a way to zip the standard output of my process to a file.

I am searching for something like:
./process | zip output.log.zip

Comment: Do keep in mind that `zip` and `gzip` are two very different beasts.

Answer (score 9):

```
# your-command | gzip > your.gz
```

Answer (score 7):

You can do this with zip too

```
your-command | zip -q output.log.zip -
```

The output from your-command will be stored in the zip with afilename of `-`.

Answer (score 0):

I did like to improve on above answer.

This should work.

`you-command | zip somename.zip -@`